# GetSubRaster and show in another canvas PaperJS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, paperjs

I am new to JavaScript and PaperJS. What I am trying to do is:

1) Load image to canvas using raster - done

```
   var imageCanvas = document.getElementById('image-canvas');
   var drawCanvas = document.getElementById('draw-canvas');
   var img = document.getElementById('img');

  imageCanvas.width = img.width;
  imageCanvas.height = img.height;
  var scope = new paper.PaperScope();

  scope.setup(drawCanvas);
  scope.setup(imageCanvas);//this will be active

  var views = [2];
  views[0] = scope.View._viewsById['image-canvas'];
  views[1] = scope.View._viewsById['draw-canvas'];
  views[0]._project.activate(); //making sure we are working on the right canvas
  raster = new paper.Raster({source:img.src, position: views[0].center});
```

2) get the sub raster of the image; the rectangle is drawn by the user using mouse drag events. But for the sake of convenience lets say I have a rectangle at position (10,10) and dimensions (100,100)
3) get the sub raster and show the preview in other drawcanvas

```
views[1]._project.activate();// activating draw-canvas
var subras = raster.getSubRaster(new paper.Path.Rectangle(new paper.Point(10,10), new paper.Size(100,100))); //Ignore if the rectangle inside is not initialized correctly
```

But, nothing happens on the draw-canvas.

I also tried using

```
var subrasdata = raster.getSubRaster(new paper.Path.Rectangle(new paper.Point(10,10), new paper.Size(100,100))).toDataURL();
```

but it gives me

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

Is there any other way to get the sub raster and pasting it in other canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of [getSubRaster()](http://paperjs.org/reference/raster/#getsubraster-rect) I used [Raster#getSubCanvas](http://paperjs.org/reference/raster/#getsubcanvas-rect) and Context#drawImage to paste in new canvas. So in short

```
canvasSrc = raster.getSubCanvas(rect);
destinationCanvasContext.drawImage(canvasSrc,0,0);
```